# Update pixel on windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

How should i update my pixel on windows phone? i cant use writepixels on my windows phone application. is there any other method on update the pixel or show the pixel?

Answer (score 0):

There are several shapes you can use in Windows Phone environment: Ellipse,Line, Path, Polygon, Polyline, Rectangle. So, basically, you can show a Rectangle with Height=1 and Width=1.

I think you can also check those tutorials: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/drawing-in-wp7-1-getting-started-and-line-shape

Comment: what function we using to draw?

Comment: Not drawing, but creating an element and adding it to the UI.

Comment: can give some example?mean it fix?

Comment: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/drawing-in-wp7-1-getting-started-and-line-shape